# How can I make a mutable.Builder for Java collections?

Tags: scala

Like the title says---I'm starting with java.util.List derived types.  (All the Scala collections have newBuider(), but of course the Java collections don't.)  I've go this so far:

```scala
case class JavaListBuilder[A,To](constructor: Constructor[To]) extends mutable.Builder[A, To] {
  private val internal = mutable.ListBuffer.empty[A]
  def addOne(elem: A): this.type = {
    internal.addOne(elem)
    this
  }
  def clear(): Unit = internal.clear
  def result(): To = constructor.newInstance(internal.result.asJava)
}

def buildTheBuilder[T,TO](t: Class[T], to: Class[TO]): mutable.Builder[T,TO] = {
  val constructor = to.getConstructor(Class.forName("java.util.Collection"))
  JavaListBuilder[T,TO](constructor)
}

val a = java.lang.Integer.valueOf(5)
val t = new java.util.ArrayList[java.lang.Integer]
val jlb = buildTheBuilder(a.getClass, t.getClass)
jlb.addOne(java.lang.Integer.valueOf(1))
jlb.addOne(java.lang.Integer.valueOf(2))
jlb.addOne(java.lang.Integer.valueOf(3))
println(jlb.result)
```

This is giving me this error:

```
[error] /Users/wmy965/git/sj_blog/src/main/scala/co.blocke.blog/Lab.scala:33:41: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Integer
[error]  required: T
[error]     jlb.addOne(java.lang.Integer.valueOf(1))
```

So it's not happy about types.  Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

What I would do, would be just implementing builder using type classes as they were intended to: by providing per-case specific implementation:

```
// example
import scala.collection.mutable

class ArrayListBuilder[A] extends mutable.Builder[A, java.util.ArrayList[A]] {
  private val intermediate = mutable.ListBuffer.empty[A]

  override def addOne(elem: A) = {
    intermediate.append(elem)
    this
  }

  override def clear() = {
    intermediate.clear()
  }

  override def result() = {
    val al = new java.util.ArrayList[A](intermediate.size)
    intermediate.foreach { elem =>
      al.add(elem)
    }
    al
  }
}
```

```
def arrayListBuilder[A]: ArrayListBuilder[A] = new ArrayListBuilder[A]

val builder = arrayListBuilder[java.lang.Integer]
builder += java.lang.Integer.valueOf(1)
builder += java.lang.Integer.valueOf(2)
builder += java.lang.Integer.valueOf(3)
builder.result
```

or shorter

```
val builder = arrayListBuilder[java.lang.Integer]
builder += 1
builder += 2
builder += 3
builder.result
```

Comment: It's possible to do that, but I don't think that's my limitation...  I don't know the element type of the collection until runtime.  I'll receive a Class of that type.  The error about Integer vs T is the issue.  I'd have to pre-know, and pre-create typed Builders for not only each collection type but also each element type.  This is for a serialization engine, so the type of the collection element is not fore-known at compile-time.